# MERGE is not working with Exec SP

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following SP,

```
    MERGE INTO DeviceCatalog DC
    USING (SELECT @UniqueID AS UniqueID) T ON (DC.UniqueID = T.UniqueID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE   

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT  

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    IF(Condition)
    BEGIN
        EXEC DeleteDeviceID;
    END;
```

I don't know how to make this work? Please help

**UPDATE:** I was able to make this,

```
    MERGE INTO DeviceCatalog DC
    USING (SELECT @UniqueID AS UniqueID) T ON (DC.UniqueID = T.UniqueID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE   

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT  

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        DELETE WHERE    [UniqueID] = @OldUniqueID; 
    END
```

But only delete statement is complaining.

Comment: are you getting any error??

Comment: yes......................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete is not supported with 'WHEN NOT MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement. You have to use 'WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE'.

```
MERGE INTO DeviceCatalog DC
USING (SELECT @UniqueID AS UniqueID) T ON (DC.UniqueID = T.UniqueID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE  SET col1='somevalue'

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT INTO  article (UniqueID) VALUES 'somevalue'

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND UniqueID = @OldUniqueID  THEN
    DELETE;
```

Comment: Let me try Thanks. If my delete execute then it will be guaranteed that insert will also execute?

Comment: I only posted delete because that's where you got error. For insert and updates you have to write the proper insert and update statements to to do what you expected. I have updated the answer with sample insert and update.

Comment: Means if delete execute it is gurenntedd that insert will also execute?

Comment: NOT MATCHED mean values is not exist in target. NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE mean value is not exist in source. So only one condition will true and only one statement will execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE INTO DeviceCatalog DC
    USING (SELECT @UniqueID AS UniqueID) T ON (DC.UniqueID = T.UniqueID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE  [write what you hav to update] 

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT  [write what to insert] 

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        DELETE WHERE    [UniqueID] = @OldUniqueID; 
    END
```

Look into this :http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/

Comment: Before posting, is you tested this?